# How to get shell script output in an OS X Application

Tags: macos, shell

I have an OS X App, it makes a call to shell script using this:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSTask *task;
    NSPipe *pipe;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self runCommand:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"command"] arguments:nil];
}

- (void)runCommand:(NSString *)cmd arguments:(NSArray *)args {
    if (task)
    {
        [task interrupt];

    }
    else
    {
        task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
        [task setLaunchPath:cmd];

        [task setArguments:args];

        pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
        [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

        NSFileHandle* fh = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

        [task launch];
        [fh readInBackgroundAndNotify];
    }
}

@end
```

The shell script `Test.command` has output text which will be displayed in Terminal window when you execute it in Terminal, but is there a way to retrieve this output in my OS X App and display it into a text view?

Comment: The script will output to `stdout`, which will *appear* in Terminal, however using a pipe, as you have set-up there, will allow the script output to be read from the file handle.  So you already have the code, so what's the problem?

Comment: If you tell the file handle to notify you have at least to implement the observer and the delegate method to receive the notification.

Comment: @trojanfoe This is what I have found on the web, but what property of the file handle should I use. This is my problem.

Comment: You need to listen for NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification on that particular file handle, and look for the NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem key in the notification's userInfo dictionary.  Note you have to re-call waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify in your handler if the data is not done yet. You can also use readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify if you just want to deal with the one notification at the end once all the data is there, or readDataToEndOfFile if you want to wait synchronously for the output.

Comment: @CarlLindberg I got nothing when trying to retrieve data from `notification.userInfo` with the `NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem` key

Comment: Whoops, my bad -- that is for NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification.  You can just use the -availableData method on the file handle itself for the NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to observe the notification event fired by the task. The order in which you register the observer and launch the command is also important. Try something like:

```
{
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:cmd];
    [task setArguments:args];

    pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
    [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

    // Observe events before launching the task, otherwise the execution
    // might end before we get the chance to register the observer.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
        selector:@selector(didCompleteReadingFileHandle:) 
        name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification 
        object:[[task standardOutput] fileHandleForReading]];

    // Make it start reading before launching.
    [[pipe fileHandleForReading] readInBackgroundAndNotify];

    // Launch it.
    [task launch];
}

- (void)didCompleteReadingFileHandle:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSData *data = [[notification userInfo]
        objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem];

    // Do something with data...
}
```

Comment: I want to get an output whenever there are one, not just when it is finished

Comment: It crashes on this line: `[[task standardOutput] readInBackgroundAndNotify];`

Comment: @TomShen did update to fix the crashing line - forgot the standardOutput returns an `id`. As for the `not just when it is finished`, that wasn't explicit in your question but I'll try to update my answer later when I get the chance.

Comment: @jweyroch it works thanks. You can ignore the first comment I made.

Comment: @TomShen okay, nice! :-)